# jQuery .addclass to multiple div

Tags: jquery, css, function, jquery-selectors, addclass

I am trying to apply the class ".lightGray" that i defined earlier on to div 4,5,7,and this current one. Not sure what I am doing wrong!

```
$("#Div8").click(function(){$("#Div4", "#Div5","#Div7","#Div8").addclass(".lightGray");});
```

Comment: Name of the method is `.addClass()`.

Answer (score 20):

Use `.addClass("lightGray");` as [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) takes className not .className

and
change

```
$("#Div4,#Div5,#Div7,#Div8")
```

to

```
 $("#Div4 ,#Div5, #Div7 ,#Div8")
```

see [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

you code becomes

```
$("#Div8").click(function(){
$("#Div4 ,#Div5 ,#Div7 ,#Div8").addClass("lightGray");
                                          ^ //remove dot from here
});
```

Comment: $("#Div3").click(function(){$("div").css("background","beige");});
   $("#Div4").click(function(){$(this).hide();});
   $("#Div5").click(function(){$("#Div4").show();});
   $("#Div6").click(function(){$(this).append("<p>I am alive!</p>");});
   $("#Div8").click(function(){$("#Div4", "#Div5","#Div7","#Div8").addclass("lightGray");});

Comment: I am still having problem are my elements represented correctly?

Comment: @RyanParker  `$("#Div4 ,#Div5 ,#Div7 ,#Div8")` this is correct selector.Check updated code.

Comment: @TusharGupta: Yes, now it's correct, as you added the commas.

Comment: You have updated the answer several times, linked to the `.addClass()` doc, but didin't notice that OP is using `addclass`!

Comment: Yeah, now it covers all the issues :)

Comment: @RyanParker accept the answer if you are satisfied http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: How can i store all tags in an array which will be affected by addClass() method, and call the array inside addclass like `addClass(arrayofElements)`. I tried to store it like `arrayofElements=["#id1","#id"]` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

when you add a class you do not need the dot.

try this instead

```
$("#Div8").click(function(){$("#Div4, #Div5, #Div7, #Div8").addClass("lightGray");});
```

Answer (score 2):

In all DIVS these I put a default class: `changeClass`, and maintain their individual IDS.

A instead of doing `$("#Div4","#Div5","#Div7","#Div8")` would suffice to make `$(".changeClass).addClass("lightGray");`

Classes can be used in more than one element at the same time and thus can manipulate several of these elements at once, saving time and lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You have made four separate selectors instead on one selector.

The commas should be inside the string:

```
$("#Div4,#Div5,#Div7,#Div8")
```

The method name is `addClass`, not `addclass`, and there shouldn't be a period before the class name:

```
$("#Div8").click(function(){$("#Div4,#Div5,#Div7,#Div8").addClass("lightGray");});
```

Comment: @RyanParker: It works fine when I test it: http://jsfiddle.net/7qXMx/ Check for any differences with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("#Div8").click(function(){
 $("#Div4,#Div5,#Div7,#Div8").addClass("lightGray");  //removed exra quotes from selecter
                                                      //removed dot(.) from class name
                                                     //Changed *addclass* to **addClass**
});
```

Comment: @RyanParker Have you wrapped the code with [document ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)?

Comment: yes it has been! This is the code with the style area as well

Comment: <style>
   body { width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; }
   div { margin: 15px; padding: 15px; cursor: pointer; }
   
   .lightGray { background-color: #cccccc; }
   .gold { background-color: gold; color: maroon; }
  </style>

Comment: @RyanParker Div8 is present initially or added after DOM ready ?

Comment: div8 is only first presented in this line. Should i make it "this" instead?

Comment: No it's ok. try putting an alert inside the click event handeler. Also check for any console error.